# Using a "local" S3 as a replacement for HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, cloudera, jets3t

I have been testing out the [most recent Cloudera CDH4](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Installing+CDH4+on+a+Single+Linux+Node+in+Pseudo-distributed+Mode#InstallingCDH4onaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudo-distributedMode-InstallingCDH4withYARNonaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudodistributedmode) `hadoop-conf-pseudo` (i.e. MRv2 or YARN) on a notebook, which has 4 cores, 8GB RAM, and an Intel X25MG2 SSD.  The OS is Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit. So far so good.

Looking at [Setting up hadoop to use S3 as a replacement for HDFS](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), I would like to do it on my notebook - on this notebook, there is a S3 emulator that my colleagues and I implemented.

Nevertheless, I can't find where I can set the [jets3t.properties](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/configuration.html#jets3t) to change the end point to `localhost`.  I downloaded the `hadoop-2.0.1-alpha.tar.gz` and searched the source without finding out a clue. There is a similar Q on SO [Using s3 as fs.default.name or HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271222/using-s3-as-fs-default-name-or-hdfs), but I want to use our own lightweight and fast S3 emulation layer, instead of AWS S3, for our experiments.

I would appreciate a hint as to how I can change the end point to a different hostname.

Regards,

--Zack